# Search with URL directly rather than the forms in the report in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, reporting-services

First of all please forgive my lack of coding knowledge.

I'm trying to use the URL of a SQL Server Report (located on our company intranet) to search for things directly rather than using the form on the report, however I can't quite seem to get it right. First of all here is a screenshot of the report:

[image]

So this is the "base URL" so to speak:

```
http://unit6sql01/ReportServer?%2fBooking+In+Pallet+Management%2fPallet+Locations+By+Pick
```

And I've tried adding various things to the end of the URL, for example:

```
&rs:Command=Render&ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue=12809878
```

And various other variations with quotes around the search string, however it either just opens the page without searching anything, or I get the following error:

> (rsUnknownReportParameter) (parameter is not defined in this report)

It's located on the company intranet and I have no admin access, so I'm not sure how much deeper I will be able to look into it, but if there's something I need to do to find the proper parameter name, please inform me and I'll see if it's possible.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server/SSRS?

Comment: "Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.50.1617.0"